# Elasticsearch - Use a transform as a source for another transform

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a transform that calculated revenue for products over a certain period. Now I want to know the revenue per category, since a category can have a 100,000 products, I would like to run a transform with the source being the transform that calculated the revenue for products.

How do I sync my category transform on the product transform? Is it possible for a transform to use an ingest pipeline, such that I can add ingest time on the transform destination index?